# $f(z) = |z|^2$ is complex differentiable only on $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

Here's my proof attempt:

$$f(z) = |z|^2$$

When $z=x+yi$, we have:

$$f(z) = x^2+y^2 + 0i$$

Doing Cauchy Riemann

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 2x = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0$$

only when $x=0$.
The second Cauchy Riemann condition is

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0 = -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 2y$$

only when $y = 0$.

Therefore, the function can be differentiable only on $(0,0)$ but we haven't proven it yet, we must show that the partial derivatives are continuous on $(0,0)$, but they are. Therefore, $f(z)$ is only complex differentiable on $(0,0)$

Is everything all right?

Comment: When $z=x+yi$, then $|z|=x^2+y^2+0i$ and $f(z)=(x^2+y^2)^2$.

Comment: @scott oops, you're rigth, but the reasoning is the same, right?

Comment: @scott ?? no ${}{}{}$

Comment: I would say instead that as $z \to 0$ : $f(z) = \mathcal{O}(|z|^2) = o(z)$ so it is complex differentiable. But as $z \to z_0\ne 0$ : $f(z) - f(z_0) = (|z| +|z_0|)(|z|-|z_0|) \ne C( z-z_0) + o(|z-z_0|)$ so it is not complex differentiable.

Comment: @scott wait, no...

Comment: I must be confused by the notation. To me, $|z|$ is the modulus of the complex number $z$, so it looked like $f(z)$ is the square of the modulus. I'll be honest: I do not recall my complex analysis, I just thought you weren't breaking the function down properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks good except when you say "we must show that the partial derivatives are continuous". It would be enough to  prove that $f$ is differentiable as a real function of two variables at the origin.

Comment: If someone can explain the down vote it would be great!